# Putting three different sided regular polygon together

Tags: geometry, elementary-number-theory

Is it possible to put three different sided regular polygon side by side together as shown?

[image]

I assume that is possible. Then, $$\dfrac {(p – 2)180}{p} + \dfrac {(q – 2)180}{q} + \dfrac {(r – 2)180}{r} = 360$$

$$(p -2)qr + (q – 2)rp + (r – 2)pq = 2pqr$$

$$pqr = 2(pq + qr + rp)$$

From that, how can I get a set of integral solution?

[Reference](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RegularPolygon.html)

Comment: What about $3,7,42$?

Comment: You may try first with $p=q=r$. Do you want to find *all* solutions?

Comment: You can also further modify it to:

$$\frac{1}{2}=\frac1p + \frac1q +\frac1r$$

Comment: @AndréNicolas I got 3, 10, 15 too, but by trial..

Comment: @Bernard Yes and preferably is a deduced result rather than trials.

Comment: @Mick: As in the answer below, there is a finite (indeed fairly small) list of candidates.  Once we have checked them all, we know the full story.  I mentioned $(3,7,42)$ first because it may be the one least likely to be found by trial. By the way, the identity $\frac{1}{k}=\frac{1}{k+1}+\frac{1}{k(k+1)}$ can be useful. For more information, please google Egyptian fractions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rewrite as $\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q}+\frac{1}{r}=\frac{1}{2}$.

Without loss of generality we may assume that $p\lt q\lt r$.

Let $p=3$. Then $q=7$ and $r=42$ works. We can get to this with a little patience. For if $p=3$, we need $\frac{1}{q}+\frac{1}{r}=\frac{1}{6}$. The only conceivable candidates for $q$ are $7$ to $11$. Try them all. After getting a "hit" with $q=7$, when you try $q=8$ you will find that $r=24$ works.

We cannot have $p\ge 6$, so we only need to explore the possibilities $p=4$ and $p=5$. In each case there is only a short list of candidates for $q$. For example, with $p=4$ all $q$ greater than $7$ are automatically ruled out for reasons of size.

*Remark:* Probably one could get the example square, hexagon, dodecagon without the above machinery.

Comment: I think you solution can isolate all the possible integral solution sets. Indeed, the examples in the remark can save us a lot of trouble but they don't fit the requirement of different sided polygons.

Comment: The example in the remark is $(4,6,12)$, different-sided.

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding your remark.